# Unable to add new User/Role in WSO2 EI 6.4.0 (Docker) via managemnt console

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, user-management

There is `WSO2 EI 6.4.0` docker container running in which trying to do `user management` task such as adding new role,adding new user, assign role to newly created user etc

When i try to add new role/listing role, it is not even shows default role such as `admin` or `internal/everyone` below ERROR got in console

> Error while listing roles. Error: Cannot change transaction isolation level in the middle of a transaction.

[image: console error]

WSO2 Log:

```
[2023-05-16 12:32:41,412] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-35] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserStoreCountClient} -  Cannot change transaction isolation level in the middle of a transaction.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.stub.UserStoreCountServiceUserStoreCounterException: UserStoreCountServiceUserStoreCounterException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.stub.UserStoreCountServiceStub.countRoles(UserStoreCountServiceStub.java:617)
```

When i try to add new user, below ERROR i got.

> Error while loading roles. Error: Error occurred while getting hybrid roles from filter : %

[image: user console error]

WSo2 Log:

```
[2023-05-16 12:34:22,826] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-19] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy} -  org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while getting hybrid roles from filter : %
[2023-05-16 12:34:22,830] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-19] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  Error occurred while getting hybrid roles from filter : %
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminStub.getRolesOfUser(UserAdminStub.java:2555)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient.getRolesOfUser(UserAdminClient.java:154)
        at org.apache.jsp.user.add_002dstep2_jsp._jspService(add_002dstep2_jsp.java:245)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
```

Note:

```
DBMS: `PostgreSQL`
DBMS Version: `12.11`
DBMS Driver: `PostgreSQL JDBC Driver`
DBMS Driver Version: `42.2.2`
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your DataSource config. This issue is reported [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/4307).

```
<testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
<validationQuery>SELECT 1; COMMIT</validationQuery>
<defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
<commitOnReturn>true</commitOnReturn>
<rollbackOnReturn>false</rollbackOnReturn>
```

Comment: Hi @ycr
Thank you so much, after adding above params in WSO2_CARBON_DB, WSO2_USER_DB and REGISTRY_DB above issue resolved, now i could able to see default roles, adding new role/new user etc.